# How to connect to SQL Server using rake task in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, rails-activerecord

I have tried connecting to remote SQL Server view using ActiveRecord sqlserver adapter:

```
@connection = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => "sqlserver",
  :dsn => "rms",
  :hosts => "xxx.xxx.xx.xx",
  :database => "V_MLS_ECOMM_STORE_SOH",
  :ports => "1521",
  :username =>  "xxxxxx",
  :passwords => "xxxxxxx")
```

`@connection.connected?` always returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
class LegacyTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection({
    :adapter  => "sqlserver",
    :host     => "host",
    :username => "user",
    :password => "pass",
    :database => "dbname"
  })
```

Reference : https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/issues/250

Comment: yeah thanks ....i am trying this in my rake task ..my db is already configured to postgres....will give a try for this .